# CSS Invalid Property Value when hr tag is modified

Tags: css

I'm learning CSS online and the above code was perfectly working when he used it. But when I did the same, browser marked`enter code here` it as an invalid property value. Moreover the border-bottom makes the hr entirely gray in color(the above mentioned code in rgba is for gray color)  overriding the border-top and the default color of hr

```
hr
{
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1PX solid #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your HTML code in order to be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove one `}` from the end , it should works perfectly ;

```
hr
{
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1PX solid #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Try formatting you css file every moment to not have this problem again.